# Using SecItemUpdate in Keychain Services

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, keychain

I have the following code to create a keychain item in the keychain:

```
    NSMutableDictionary* dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [dict setObject: (__bridge id) kSecClassGenericPassword  forKey: (__bridge id) kSecClass];
    [dict setObject: MYKEY           forKey: (__bridge id) kSecAttrService];
    [dict setObject: @"0" forKey: (__bridge id) kSecValueData];
    SecItemAdd ((__bridge CFDictionaryRef) dict, NULL);
```

Which works fine. Can anyone give the syntax for what exactly to put for SecItemUpdate if I want to change this item?

UPDATE: with the following:

```
NSMutableDictionary *query = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
NSMutableDictionary *attributesToUpdate = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

[query setObject: (__bridge id) kSecClassGenericPassword forKey: (__bridge id) kSecClass];
[query setObject: MYKEY forKey: (__bridge id) kSecAttrService];
[query setObject: (id) kCFBooleanTrue forKey: (__bridge id) kSecReturnData];

NSString *numberOfBalloonsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", numberOfBalloonsUsed];
NSData *numberOfBalloonsData = [numberOfBalloonsString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[attributesToUpdate setObject: numberOfBalloonsData forKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData];

OSStatus error = SecItemUpdate ((__bridge CFDictionaryRef) query, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef) attributesToUpdate);
NSLog(@"Error #: %ld", error);
```

I'm getting the error code -50 =

> One or more parameters passed to the function were not valid.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`SecItemUpdate` is terribly documented.

The `query` parameter of `SecItemUpdate` is documented as a query (as used in other functions) as well as the vague statement: "Specify the items whose values you wish to change". This seems to imply that you must include the existing attribute value in this dictionary that you want to change but I don't think you do. I've found you can use the same `query` you use to get attributes for the item you want to update.

The `attributes` parameter should be the result of `SecItemCopyMatching` with the `kSecValueData` key and value added and any attributes changed.

Comment: Thanks yeah this is true. In the end, there is a lot wrong with my code up there, I ended up using the ARC version of Apples KeychainItemWrapper (https://gist.github.com/dhoerl/1170641) and it ended up being perfect for what I was trying to accomplish.

Comment: Can one just use `kSecItemAdd` every-time, and simply overwrite existing items? And this way never need to call `kSecItemUpdate` at all?

Answer (score 3):

A late answer, but an answer nonetheless:

I've been struggling with updating items in the keychain as well, my context was a little different though.

---

#### What happened:

I could add a keychain item with success (using `SecItemAdd`), but calling `SecItemUpdate` on the same item failed with the notorious `errSecParam -50`.
What was even worse; if the keychain item already existed (hence I called `SecItemUpdate` immediately), the update went through with no problems at all.
I've got absolutely no idea as of why that happened...

#### How I fixed it:

Quite simple actually, I just removed "params" until the big bad `-50` was satisfied. This happened when I removed the `kSecClass` from the dictionary I retrieved from `kSecItemCopyMatching`.
Here's my code:

```
 // If the item already exists, we update it instead
if (SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)self.searchQueryDict, (CFTypeRef *)&foundItem) == errSecSuccess) {
    NSMutableDictionary *updateDict = (__bridge NSMutableDictionary *)foundItem;
    [updateDict addEntriesFromDictionary:dictToSave];
    [updateDict removeObjectForKey:(__bridge id)kSecClass];

    OSStatus updateSuccess = SecItemUpdate((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)self.updateQueryDict,
                                           (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)updateDict);
    NSAssert(updateSuccess == errSecSuccess, @"Couldn't save the dirty info to the keychain, might want to log the updateSuccess (%d)", updateSuccess);
}
```

As a reference I used the following dictionaries

`self.searchQueryDict` contained:

```
(__bridge id)kSecClass              : (__bridge id)kSecClassGenericPassword              
(__bridge id)kSecAttrService        : service                                            
(__bridge id)kSecAttrGeneric        : [identifier dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
(__bridge id)kSecMatchLimit         : (__bridge id)kSecMatchLimitOne                     
(__bridge id)kSecReturnAttributes   : (__bridge id)kCFBooleanTrue                        
(__bridge id)kSecReturnData         : (__bridge id)kCFBooleanTrue
```

`self.updateQueryDict` contained:

```
(__bridge id)kSecClass       : (__bridge id)kSecClassGenericPassword,
(__bridge id)kSecAttrService : service,
(__bridge id)kSecAttrGeneric : [identifier dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
```

`dictToSave` should contain the values (in the correct format) which needs to change

Removing the `kSecClass` fixed the problem for me.